# Faster select Max SQL Query

Tags: sql, db2, query-optimization

Here is the query to select the Config Type that has the Max number of rows.
Is there another way that is just as fast as the second query to select the data?

```
select CONFIG_TYPE, MAX(COUNTING) FROM 
(select CONFIG_TYPE, COUNT(*) as COUNTING FROM NOTIFICATION_CONFIG GROUP BY CONFIG_TYPE)
WHERE COUNTING =
(select MAX(COUNTING) FROM 
(select COUNT(*) as COUNTING FROM NOTIFICATION_CONFIG GROUP BY CONFIG_TYPE)
)GROUP BY CONFIG_TYPE
```

This second query will do the job in 1 search, unlike the other that does it in 2.

```
select CONFIG_TYPE, COUNTING FROM
(select CONFIG_TYPE, COUNT(*) as COUNTING FROM NOTIFICATION_CONFIG
GROUP BY CONFIG_TYPE ORDER BY COUNTING DESC FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY)
```

just wondering if there was another way to do this.

Comment: I am using IBM DB2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions!

```
SELECT c.*
FROM (SELECT CONFIG_TYPE, COUNT(*) as COUNTING,
             RANK() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM NOTIFICATION_CONFIG
      GROUP BY CONFIG_TYPE
     ) c
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

This uses `RANK()`, so it will return all maximum values (in the case of ties).  If you want one arbitrary maximum returned in the case of ties, then use `ROW_NUMBER()` instead.  Or, if you don't want ties, you can do:

```
SELECT CONFIG_TYPE, COUNT(*) as COUNTING
FROM NOTIFICATION_CONFIG
GROUP BY CONFIG_TYPE
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just messed up

```
select CONFIG_TYPE, MAX(COUNTING) 
FROM  ( select CONFIG_TYPE, COUNT(*) as COUNTING 
        FROM NOTIFICATION_CONFIG 
        GROUP BY CONFIG_TYPE 
      )
WHERE COUNTING = ( select MAX(COUNTING) 
                   FROM ( select COUNT(*) as COUNTING 
                          FROM NOTIFICATION_CONFIG 
                          GROUP BY CONFIG_TYPE
                        )
                 )
GROUP BY CONFIG_TYPE
```